# how to compare the current time to a variable in a .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to make a redirection after a deadline on my site.

currently everything works correctly if I write this :

```
RewriteEngine On

SetEnv DEADLINE 16/06/2022_19h30

RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY}/%{TIME_MON}/%{TIME_YEAR}_%{TIME_HOUR}h%{TIME_MIN} >=16/06/2022_19h30
RewriteRule ^index.php$ read_only/index.html [L]
```

the advantage of using an environment variable is that I can use it elsewhere in a PHP file

**So is there a way to test between the current time and the DEADLINE variable?**

Comment: This is not what the rewriting module has been made for. You want a full fledged programming language here, so a router script of some sort. Another option would be to replace or prepend your existing .htaccess configuration file by means of a cron job that triggers at the time of the deadline.

Comment: "currently everything works correctly" - Although not with the _condition_ as posted. `>=` is a lexicographical string comparison. So, `20/05/2022_00h00 >= 16/06/2022_19h30` is _true_, which is clearly not the intention. The date/time string needs to be ordered from most significant to least significant. eg. `YYYY/MM/DD_HHhMM`.

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for correcting me, I am only a beginner, I had not paid attention to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but you need to set your variable using `SetEnvIf` directive, so that it is available for evaluation in .htaccess `RewriteCond`:

Define this variable first:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ DEADLINE=20220616193000
```

Then use it in .htaccess using `RewriteCond` expressions:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "%{TIME} -ge env('DEADLINE')"
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ read_only/index.html [L,NC]
```

Due to use of [`expr`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) in `RewriteCond`, it will require Apache 2.4+

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, yes it was a typo due to my testing this rule locally :)

Comment: The code after modification seems to work correctly, thank you very much @anubhava !